# Проверка, что стринг содержит только символы UTF-8

Tags: c#, utf-8, кодировка, m3u

Я пытаюсь написать парсер списка воспроизведеия в формате M3U8. Я использую С#. Согласно HTTP Live Streaming 2nd Edition фаил списка должен быть закодирован в UTF-8. Как можно проверить, что стринг содержит только символы в кодировке UTF-8?

Comment: Просто читайте из потока массив байт и собирайте из него строку и перехватывайте ошибки

Comment: Спасибо! Вы не могли бы проиллюстрировать примером?

Comment: Ага, как оказалось, `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` не бросает исключение, если на входе невалидные данные...

Comment: Смотрите этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2213965/6766879 и используйте класс отсюда: http://utf8checker.codeplex.com/